# How to loop through dataclass in Python?

Tags: python, variables, python-dataclasses

I would like to loop through a dataclass in python, to find all cars, which fit a certain criteria, however, the code never works, because the variable gets interpreted as an attribute, and not a variable.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class cars:
    year: int = 0
    model: str = "unknown"
    PS: int = 0
    colour: str = "unknown"

car_1 = cars(year = 1980, colour = "brown")
car_2 = cars(year = 1999, colour = "black", PS = 82)

owned_cars = [car_1, car_2]

criteria = input("Which criteria to search for? year, model, PS, colour")

for car in owned_cars:
    value = car.criteria
    print(value, car)
```

```
AttributeError: 'cars' object has no attribute 'criteria'
```

When using:

```
value = car.year
```

the code runs fine. How can I tell python, it should interpret criteria as the variable and use its content, instead of its name?

Comment: I'd try to type in `__dict__` if I were a user of that program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with `car` being a dataclass. It's just how Python attributes work. If you want to look up an attribute by its name in a string, use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
value = getattr(car, criteria)
```

Comment: not an answer, and not a duplicate but great Q.

Comment: @qrtLs: I'm not sure what you mean by that. This answers how to turn a string like `"year"` into an attribute lookup equivalent to `car.year`, which was what the questioner wanted (as judged by their choice to accept this answer). It may be that you have some other issue you should ask about separately.